# Bulk insert with auto increment

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert text file into SQL Server, but I just couldn't add with Id auto increment. Text file like 2.7 gb. I tried T-SQL import or Excel but I couldn't fix it that I want.

```
BULK INSERT tablob 
FROM 'C:\Users\berka\Project\addd\text.txt' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')`
```

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
    Id int,
    Url nvarchar(500),
);
```

Text file looks like this

```
http://xxxxxx.com
http://xxxxxx.com
```

Comment: The [BULK INSERT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) states "If the data file does not contain values for the identity column in the table or view, use a format file to specify that the identity column in the table or view is to be skipped when importing data; SQL Server automatically assigns unique values for the column".

Comment: That data doesn't match the definition of your table. The first column in your table is an `int`, however, it looks like you are 2 URLs delimited by white space (`' '`). A URL is definitely not an `int`.

Comment: I know that table doesn't match with the text. I was trying to insert urls into second column, I just couldn't configure that bulk. insert code. Im expecting like . Id=1 url =http://abc.xyz

Answer (score 1):

You need identity

```
CREATE TABLE table( Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                    Url nvarchar(500));
```